# STM32F103 Debug Error - Cannot Access Target

Tags: stm32, debugging, keil, cortex-m3

Im having problem at debugging, tried to load basic led toggle program for test purpose and its work fine but when i tried to debug it, im getting " Cannot Access Target, Shutting Down Debug Session ". My other concern is this device has 256 KBytes Flash Memory though at keil there is only 512 KBytes option. Hoping to get some information from you about this problem. Thanks for your time.

MCU = STM32F103CVT6

IDE= Keil 5.34.0.0

[image: Debug_Settings_1][image: Debug_Settings_2][image: Command Error][image: Debug Error Type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i though this problem was kinda weird but when i found out cubemx generated this code
"__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_SWJ_DISABLE();"  in "void HAL_MspInit(void)" function. I kinda laughed ^^ and delete it. People who have a similar problem hope will see this answer before spending much time...

Comment: What's that about?

Comment: Basically disables the SWJ pin for using other purposes. I m writing %99 of my code manually without using cubemx, so when i tried cubemx, did not know that at  default settings it disables the debug pin.